# Textures appear on Material preview Mode but not in render mode

Tags: rendering, texture-coordinates

I'm trying to make a large scale ocean.

[image]

I've made the texture in node editor using some bakes. So far is looking like on the image above but if I change to render view this is what I'm getting:
[image]

This is the nodes I'm using:
[image]

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
I'm trying to render the scene to see the final result but the textures are not shown on the final rendered animation. I'm just getting a plain circle with no textures.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/239085/107598. You're using Displacement but the material settings are set to "Bump Only" and your ocean might have not enough geometry to do the displacement.

Comment: Hi Blunder, sorry for the delay. I've checked that and I have "displacement only" on the displacement menu selection and still getting the same blue circle.

Comment: Ok. And the other question? Is this plane subdivided? Is there a Subdivision Surface modifier as described in the linked question?

Comment: I have 2 subdivisions on the object. One of them is the same as the linked question, the other one is just as default. Still no ocean on the final render.

Comment: Wait... 1) Displacement maps are greyscaled images. Why do you swap the G and B channels of your image as you would do with a DirectX normal map? This is not needed. Even if you are using an RGB normal map Blender will convert it to greyscale values and use it for the height 2) Your base color is nearly black and *Roughness* is 0.0. This would make your water look like black oil. Why does it look blueish? 3) Are you sure the image sequence works? The last time I used one I had to tick *[X] Auto Refresh* of the Image Texture node 4) maybe you want to share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: (After the upload, you need to paste the new URL address here. It's key to access the file. The file limit is 25 MB.)

Comment: Hi Blunder I finally got it working. I've checked the autorefresh you mentioned and now it's rendering perfectly.