# PBR textures not looking bumpy

Tags: texturing, pbr

I am trying to use pbr textures with node wrangler but i am getting weird results and ugly effects, even with all maps, it looks like as if the maps are not set in the right direction. I dont have GPU, maybe thats why this looks so ugly? i use intel HD graphics 1400. i was even trying to model the roofing by hand but this would take very long time and i think its not worth.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: Goal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your material only has "fake" bumping. To have actual "real" 3D bumps, follow these steps:

In your material, add a *Displacement* node right before the Displacement input socket of the *Material Output* node:

[image]

Then, be sure that your *Render Engine* is set to *Cycles* and enable the *Experimental Feature Set*:

[image]

Then select your roof object, and add a *Subdivision Surface Modifier* to it, set it to *Simple*, and check *Adaptive Subdivision*:

[image]

And finally, go into your *Material Properties* and under *Settings > Surface* set the *Displacement* mode to *Displacement and Bump*:

[image]

This should give you accurate 3D bumping based on your image texture.

Also just as an advice, it's always beneficial to use the latest stable version of Blender: https://www.blender.org/download/

Comment: Thank you so much Geri!!!

Comment: oh btw i dont use the newer version because i dont have GPU. new version require Opengl